# using variables in i18n resource files

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, i18next

**Hello everyone,**

I'm using the [i18n](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#i18n) (for require.js) library to load my translated strings from resource files based on the user's language.
I have used [this](http://resthub.github.io/docs/backbone/internationalization/) approach, since I'm using both backbone and require.js in my project. But I'd like also to put an argument/variable to the string stored in the i18n resource file.

Let's say this is the i18n resource file

```
define({
    'root': {
        'options': {
            'test': 'Yellow {variable.x}'
        }
    },
    "en-us": true
});
```

now I'm not really sure whether it's possible possible to pass an argument to evaluate the variable inside the resource file.

```
define(['underscore', 'backbone', 'models/model', 'templates/template' , 'i18n!nls/resource'], function ( _, Backbone, tModel, template, resource) {
    var TooltipView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el : $('#test'),

        initialize: function(options){
            this.model = new tModel();
        },

        render: function(){
            var $el = this.$el;
                if(template.length != 0){
                    var compiledTemplate = template['test']( resource, { variable: "14"} ) /// loads pre-compiled template ///          
                    $el.html(compiledTemplate);
                }else{
                    console.log(" [e] No template found. ");
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return TooltipView;
});
```

I'd like to achieve this output:

```
<h1> Yellow 14 </h1>
```

Comment: looks like u need `sprintf`, some think like this -  template['test'](sprintf(resource, { variable: "14"})); and update `options` hash 'test': 'Yellow %(variable)s' - http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Evgeniy suggested , I should have used the **sprintf** library for this case.

Solution:

**template:**

```
<span> <%= sprintf( data.text, data.id ) %>  </span>
```

**resource file:**

```
define({
    'root': {
        'options': {
            'test': 'Yellow %i'
        }
    },
    "en-us": true
});
```

then in view I needed to change this:

```
define(['underscore', 'backbone', 'models/model', 'templates/template' , 'i18n!nls/resource', 'sprintf'], function ( _, Backbone, tModel, template, resource, s_utils) {
...
..
var data = _.extend( resource, { id: 11 } , s_utils );  // this enabled me to use the sprintf function in my template file. 
var compiledTemplate = template['test']( data ) /// loads pre-compiled template ///          
                    $el.html(compiledTemplate);

..
    return TooltipView;
});
```